# How to make validation of entry field in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want only digits and sign '.' were printed in my Entry field. But after running this code I can type only digits or only sign '.'(I try to type '2.45', but point is not typing after '2'. If I try to type '.45', '45' is not typing after '.' ). How can I resolve this problem?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
entry = Entry(width=10)
entry.pack()

def correct(inp):
    if inp.isdigit():
        return True
    elif inp == ".":
        return True
    elif inp == "":
        return True
    else:
        return False

reg = root.register(correct)

entry.config(validate='key', validatecommand = (reg, '%P'))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation function isn't written incorrectly…and I think this would be an easier way of doing what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(width=10)
entry.pack()

def correct(inp):
    """ Determine if inp value is a valid floating point number. """
    try:
        float(inp)
    except ValueError:
        return inp == ''  # Consider empty string valid.
    else:
        return True

reg = root.register(correct)

entry.config(validate='key', validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. It works almost correctly. The only thing is what I can't delete the last digit from my Entry field

Comment: If you want the empty string to be accepted, you'll need to handle it as a special case. I've modified my answer to do this.